# Sending jQuery variable to PHP Script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Afternoon all,

I have the following code which works fine, apart from i need to send the variable `itemID` to my php script as `$_POST['deleteClientID']`. Now i know that `data: itemID,` is wrong but i'm unsure what it should be?

```
function deleteItem(item){
    if (confirm("Do you wish to delete this item?")) {
        //alert(item);
        var parent = item.closest('.row');
        var itemID = item.data('client-id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/delete_client.php',
            data: itemID,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert(itemID);
                parent.switchClass("", "redBG", 300, "easeInOutQuad");
            },
            success: function() {
                parent.slideUp(500,function() {
                    parent.remove();
                });
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this should be data: itemID, like this data: "itemID="+itemID,!!!

Comment: data : {deleteClientID : itemId}. Then use $_POST['deleteClientID'] in your script

Comment: Did you read the doc : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ? Example at the bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data needs to be an object, key: value

```
data: { deleteClientID: itemID }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
data: { deleteClientID: itemID }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function deleteItem(item){
    if (confirm("Do you wish to delete this item?")) {
        //alert(item);
        var parent = item.closest('.row');
        var itemID = item.data('client-id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/delete_client.php',
            data: {deleteClientID:itemID},
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert(itemID);
                parent.switchClass("", "redBG", 300, "easeInOutQuad");
            },
            success: function() {
                parent.slideUp(500,function() {
                    parent.remove();
                });
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```